# Expanding the search on Extension Library Layot Control Search?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

We use the search feature in the Extension Library Layout control to search a view.   It works as expected.    But we wold like to expand that search.

The documents in the view each could have one to many "comment" docments. The documents are displayed on the issue xpage with an "embedded" view.  The comment is associated to the issue via the parent's UNID.  There is a parentUNID field on each comment but the comment document  is not a traditional response document.

We would like to be able to search all issues and their comments without having to display the comment in the view.  When the search is performed, we want only the issue document to display in the view.

Is it possible to expand the search (with out creating my own search box) to search the comments as well as the issues?   If so how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A repeat control may be the best way to do it. Then you can search a view containing both. For each row, if the document's Form is an issue, display that. If it's a comment, get the "parent" and display the values from that.

You might want to make each row contain a Panel, so you can attach a dominoDocument datasource for each row containing the documentId of the issue (remembering to set ignoreRequestParams of course!)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think you misunderstood me. :)  What I want to do is to have the search control also search the comment documents for what was enterd in the search box.  I really don't want to dispay the comments in the view.  And we are currently using a view container to display the issues.